# Get name and photo from v2.0 app scoped Facebook id, without an access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get name and photo from v2.0 app scoped Facebook id, without an access token?

This used to be possible in v1.0 (with original Facebook ids), see the [link](https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=1452776161639888&fields=first_name,picture).

But in v2.0 with app scoped ids, I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

This seems to me to be a common use case, where in a game, playerA is logged into Facebook and playerB is not using Facebook, and you want playerB to be able to obtain playerA's Facebook name and photo, without logging in.

Answer (score 2):

That's intentional - in v2.0 no API calls can be made without an access token except the call to retrieve a user's profile picture

You should store the name in your own database, and retrieve the photo using the app scoped ID - since you'll already be deciding which users to show based on your own database you should already have both pieces of information in your system and not need to fetch anything from Facebook's API without an access token